# Preventing blurring of fast-moving objects on the screen

Tags: python, image, qt, animation, antialiasing

I'm writing a desktop application in Python using the Qt framework, and it involves whisking images across the screen at a fairly quick pace. I do this in a pretty straightforward way:

- For each item, create a Qlabel object with the associated image
- Start a timer for each Qlabel using startTimer
- timerEvent leads to a call that looks something like: self.move(self.x() + SPEED, self.y()) where SPEED is some small number of pixels.

This works, but even at modest speeds (say 500 pixels per second) the images (in this case I'm using playing cards) are really painful to look at. There's a lot of horizontal blurring. I thought that I might be able to mitigate this by changing the frequency with which the timer goes off (so that the images get moved a larger amount fewer times, or a smaller amount more times), but this doesn't really help.

Can anyone explain what's causing this, and how I might fix it? I've read the Wikipedia article on [Motion Blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_blur), but it didn't help much. When someone asked me what caused it, I said something about monitor response times, but I wasn't convinced of it, and when they asked me "So how come that doesn't happen when you play a video game?" I couldn't give an answer.

**Edit**: As requested, [here's a paste](http://dpaste.com/hold/446403/) of a toy program that exhibits the problem. Takes a path to an image file as a command line argument.

Comment: Motion blur us usually something you add to computer graphics to make fast-moving objects *less* painful to look at.  It's a difficult process to do efficiently and is usually (I think) handled by a specialized video card.  To really understand the issue,  I think we need a very detailed description of what it looks like along with specs on the display, computer and it would help if you provided the code.  What do you get when you do a screen capture during this event?

Comment: @Paul Good question. When I take a screenshot, the images look perfectly crisp, so I think it's definitely a human optical effect at work. The code itself is fairly large and complex, but I'll see if I can cook up a small example program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Does the object look somewhat disjointed or garbled?  Does the playing card look like it has been chopped into sections horizontally?

Comment: The only way I can describe it is 'blurry'. It's basically as if it leaves a trail behind it. I've posted some example code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like flicker from a lack of [double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering).  I'm not sure exactly how to solve it in your particular toolkit, but that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like you're exactly right. Searching for double buffering gives me a lot to work with. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any examples or guides for the version of Qt I'm using (PyQt4), so I may end up asking another question later. You've definitely answered this one for me though. :)

Comment: **Update**: Actually, is it possible that it's something other than lack of double buffering? I just read in the [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwidget.html#transparency-and-double-buffering) that "Since Qt 4.0, QWidget automatically double-buffers its painting, so there is no need to write double-buffering code in paintEvent() to avoid flicker."

Comment: @Coquelicot, it sure looks like it to me, but like I said I don't know enough about Qt, so I'll admit I could be wrong.  You might have better luck asking on the Qt [forums](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums).